# Rails 6 and action mailbox setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I've recently upgraded to `ruby 2.6.0p0 and rails 6.0.2.1`. And previously I had `ruby 2.3 and rails 5.2`.

When I open up existing apps and just `bundle update` and then `rails s` everything is working just fine:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.0.2.1 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.12.0 (ruby 2.6.0-p0), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
```

But when I try to implement the new [action mailbox](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailbox_basics.html) feature by entering this initially `rails action_mailbox:install` it returns the following error, this same error occurs if I enter this `rails action_text:install`.

```
rails aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'action_mailbox:install' (See the list of available tasks with `rails --tasks`)
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that task can't be found, then it's generally one of two things:

1. Your terminal is using a different version of rails when you run the script (maybe try `bundle exec rails action_mailbox:install`?)
2. Some pieces were missed during the [Upgrade Task](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#the-update-task) that aren't requiring the new action mailbox tasks.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction @codenamev ! :)))  It was as simple as adding the following to the application.rb file`require "active_storage/engine"` and `require "action_mailbox/engine"`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.
Be sure, you require `action_mailbox/engine` in `application.rb`

```
require 'action_mailbox/engine'
```